# Caching package

Tags: php, caching, composer-php, packagist

I need to know a good purely php based composer package. I need to be able to cache viewed URL's for 72 hours and be able to call on the cache to check if a given URL is already cached.

I have used packagist but in my current inexperience most of the composer packages there just don't tell me what I need to know. I want to stick with the basics, no major dependencies. Even if it will end up taking a few more steps.

If anyone knows a composer package that could fit my needs and could point me in the right direction I would be highly appreciative.

Thank you very much for your assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://packagist.org/packages/sonata-project/cache

Try this one. Docs should help you get it integrated and use it.